# execute 2 stored procedures on button click event vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have 2 stored procedures (InsertToCustomer) and (InsertToRepair) which i need to run under one button click event. However when i click the button only the InsertToRepair Procedure works and stores it in the 'Repair' table but none of the info for customers gets stored in the 'Customer' Table

Below is my vb.Net code for this

```vb
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBookRepair.Click
    'Declare variables

    Dim bookedInBy, deviceType, bookedInDate, fName, lName, address, contactNum, altContactNum, deviceName, accessories, devicePassword, repairType, technicalNotes, repairStatus, completedNotes As String
    Dim trackingNum As Integer

    'Setting Date

    bookedInDate = txtBookedInDate.Text

    'Assigning variables
    bookedInBy = DDLBookedInBy.SelectedItem.Text
    deviceType = DDLDeviceType.SelectedItem.Text
    trackingNum = txtTrackingNumber.Text
    fName = txtFname.Text
    lName = txtLname.Text
    address = txtAddress.Text
    contactNum = txtContactNum.Text
    altContactNum = txtAltContactNum.Text
    deviceName = txtDeviceName.Text
    accessories = DDLAccessories.SelectedItem.Text
    devicePassword = txtDevicePassword.Text
    repairType = DDLRepairType.SelectedItem.Text
    technicalNotes = txtTechnical.Text
    repairStatus = DDLRepairStatus.SelectedItem.Text
    completedNotes = txtCompletedNotes.Text


    Dim sqlCS As String

    sqlCS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Database").ConnectionString
    Try
        Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(sqlCS)
            Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand

            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "InsertToRepair"
            sqlCmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

            sqlConn.Open()
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tracking_Number", trackingNum)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Booked_in_by", bookedInBy)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Device_Type", deviceType)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Booked_In_Date", bookedInDate)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Device_Name", deviceName)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Accessories", accessories)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DevicePassword", devicePassword)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Repair_Type", repairType)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Technical_Notes", technicalNotes)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Completed_Notes", completedNotes)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RepairStatus", repairStatus)

            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            sqlCmd.CommandText = "InsertToCustomer"
            sqlCmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", fName)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", lName)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", contactNum)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alternative_Contact_Number", altContactNum)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerAddress", address)

            sqlConn.Close()

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

        StatusLabel.Text = ex.ToString


    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to execute the query again. Same as what you are doing for Repair. Re-use sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() to execute SQL command for inserting data into customer table

Comment: Something is not right here. You execute the InsertToRepair before setting the parameters. If the SP requires parameters you should get an exception. Then you execute again the SP now with the parameters  correctly inserted, finally you add parameters for the second SP but don't clear the parameters of the first call. It should be another exception

Comment: Another option: create an SP that calls the 2 current ones.  Then your .NET code only has to make one database call.

Comment: Do you intend that the SQL parameters for the first query are also available to the second query, or did you forget to do `sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear()` before creating the second set of parameters?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Intended for the SQL Parameters to be also available to the 2nd query. But maybe thinking in this case it would be better to perhaps clear parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Three issues with the code I see are:

1. Executing `sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` prematurely - that's the last operation performed after setting up the `SqlCommand` object you'd do
2. Re-use of `SqlCommand` object for two different operations
3. Not wrapping `SqlCommand` objects in a `Using` statement

**EDIT:**

As @Andrew Morton has commented, it may be that you meant to re-use parameters from one query to the next, in which case the two `SqlCommand` `Using` statements should be merged.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBookRepair.Click
    'Declare variables
    Dim bookedInBy, deviceType, bookedInDate, fName, lName, address, contactNum, altContactNum, deviceName, accessories, devicePassword, repairType, technicalNotes, repairStatus, completedNotes As String
    Dim trackingNum As Integer

    'Setting Date
    bookedInDate = txtBookedInDate.Text

    'Assigning variables
    bookedInBy = DDLBookedInBy.SelectedItem.Text
    deviceType = DDLDeviceType.SelectedItem.Text
    trackingNum = txtTrackingNumber.Text
    fName = txtFname.Text
    lName = txtLname.Text
    address = txtAddress.Text
    contactNum = txtContactNum.Text
    altContactNum = txtAltContactNum.Text
    deviceName = txtDeviceName.Text
    accessories = DDLAccessories.SelectedItem.Text
    devicePassword = txtDevicePassword.Text
    repairType = DDLRepairType.SelectedItem.Text
    technicalNotes = txtTechnical.Text
    repairStatus = DDLRepairStatus.SelectedItem.Text
    completedNotes = txtCompletedNotes.Text

    Dim sqlCS As String

    sqlCS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Database").ConnectionString
    Try
        Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(sqlCS)
            sqlConn.Open()
            Using sqlCmd as New SqlCommand
                sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "InsertToRepair"
                sqlCmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tracking_Number", trackingNum)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Booked_in_by", bookedInBy)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Device_Type", deviceType)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Booked_In_Date", bookedInDate)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Device_Name", deviceName)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Accessories", accessories)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DevicePassword", devicePassword)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Repair_Type", repairType)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Technical_Notes", technicalNotes)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Completed_Notes", completedNotes)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RepairStatus", repairStatus)

                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End Using
            Using sqlCmd as New SqlCommand
                sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "InsertToCustomer"
                sqlCmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", fName)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", lName)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", contactNum)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alternative_Contact_Number", altContactNum)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerAddress", address)

                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        StatusLabel.Text = ex.ToString
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree that a `SqlCommand` object _can_ be reused, but not without clearing its parameters collection between uses.  It's safest to simply use another object.

Comment: It may be that the OP wants the parameters from the first SP to be used in the second SP. I asked for clarification. The code presented may be both more clever and more wrong than it first appears.

Comment: ... and not calling `sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` the second time as @rach commented... or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There is one major issue which Steve pointed out in the comments: the parameters must be added before calling the command which uses them. Otherwise it is like trying to bake a cake before you have any ingredients - it just doesn't make sense.

A secondary issue which might come up is that `AddWithValue` is not reliable. [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) has information on that.

As a style note, it is recommended to assign a value to variable when you Dim it rather than do the two separately. [I can't find the MSDN page about that right now.] Also, if you list the variables in the order in which they are used, it can be easier if you ever need to read over or debug the code in the future.

The variables `trackingNum` and `bookedInDate` look like they should be an Integer and DateTime, respectively, so you should explicitly make and use them so. If you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) then Visual Studio will helpfully point out anomalies with variable types.

Rather than checking of all the user input for validity (which you really should do - never trust user input - a cat might have walked across the keyboard), I factored out the sending-to-database code so that I could enclose it all in one Try...Catch.

So, your code could look something like this:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Sub SendDataToDB()

        Dim trackingNum As Integer = CInt(txtTrackingNumber.Text)
        Dim bookedInDate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(txtBookedInDate.Text)

        Dim bookedInBy = DDLBookedInBy.SelectedItem.Text
        Dim deviceType = DDLDeviceType.SelectedItem.Text
        Dim deviceName = txtDeviceName.Text
        Dim accessories = DDLAccessories.SelectedItem.Text
        Dim devicePassword = txtDevicePassword.Text
        Dim repairType = DDLRepairType.SelectedItem.Text
        Dim technicalNotes = txtTechnical.Text
        Dim completedNotes = txtCompletedNotes.Text
        Dim repairStatus = DDLRepairStatus.SelectedItem.Text

        Dim fName = txtFname.Text
        Dim lName = txtLname.Text
        Dim contactNum = txtContactNum.Text
        Dim altContactNum = txtAltContactNum.Text
        Dim address = txtAddress.Text

        Dim sqlCS As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Database").ConnectionString

        Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(sqlCS)
            Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand()

                sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn
                sqlCmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

                ' first store the repair data... '
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "InsertToRepair"

                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Tracking_Number", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, .Value = trackingNum})
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Booked_In_Date", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, .Value = bookedInDate})
                'TODO: Set the .Size to be the same as the declaration in the database. '
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Booked_in_by", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Size = 100, .Value = bookedInBy})
                'TODO: Convert the following AddWithValue to Add as above. '
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Device_Type", deviceType)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Device_Name", deviceName)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Accessories", accessories)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DevicePassword", devicePassword)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Repair_Type", repairType)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Technical_Notes", technicalNotes)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Completed_Notes", completedNotes)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RepairStatus", repairStatus)

                sqlConn.Open()
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                ' now store the customer data, with additional parameters... '
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "InsertToCustomer"

                'TODO: Use Add instead of AddWithValue. '
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", fName)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", lName)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", contactNum)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alternative_Contact_Number", altContactNum)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerAddress", address)

                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                sqlConn.Close()

            End Using

        End Using

    End Sub

    'TODO: Give Button1 a meaningful name. '
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            SendDataToDB()
        Catch ex As Exception
            StatusLabel.Text = ex.ToString
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

(Although I used Option Infer On, I explicitly typed the first two variables for emphasis to the reader.)

From the deprecated documentation part of this site regarding working with SQL parameters:

- Sql parameters type and size mismatch is a common cause of insert/ updated/ select failure
- Give your Sql parameters meaningful names just like you do variables in your code
- Specify the database data type of the column you are using, this ensures the wrong parameter types is not used which could lead to unexpected results
- Validate your incoming parameters before you pass them into the command (as the saying goes, "garbage in, garbage out"). Validate incoming values as early as possible in the stack
- Use the correct types when assigning your parameter values, example: do not assign the string value of a DateTime, instead assign an actual DateTime instance to the value of the parameter
- Specify the size of string-type parameters. This is because SQL Server can re-use execution plans if the parameters match in type and size. Use -1 for MAX
- Do not use the method AddWithValue, the main reason is it is very easy to forget to specify the parameter type or the precision/scale when needed.

P.S. The names like "Device_Type" and "RepairStatus" are inconsistent - it's easier if you pick one naming convention and stick to it, or else you will be trying to use "DeviceType" and "Repair_Status" and wonder why they aren't working.